# Pass parameter to texlua script

Tags: lua

Calling `texlua file.lua` on the command line runs the file through a Lua interpreter.  Is it possible to give arguments to the script?

For instance, in

```
-- file.lua
io.write(3.4 + 5.6)
io.write("\n")
```

How do I make 5.6 into a parameter given on the command line?

Comment: When egreg and I wrote [`checkcites`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/checkcites), we opted for running it under `texlua` because the interpreter is available on every modern TeX distribution. `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda My goal is to provide a couple of LuaTeX-like functionalities in XeTeX by calling a `texlua` script within `\immediate\write18`.

Comment: cool, the idea sounds awesome! `:)` Well, *you* are a synonymous of awesomeness. `:)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
-- file.lua
io.write(arg[1] + arg[2])
io.write("\n")
```

---

```
$ texlua file.lua 103.4 5.6
109
```

Comment: Just to expand David's answer: Lua creates a table with all the command line arguments in a global variable named `arg`. The script name is in the index `0`, the first argument is in `1`, and so on. If you try negative indices, you go back in the line, so in David's example, `arg[-1] == texlua`. `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda But you can't go further back than `texlua`, i.e., in `time texlua file.lua`, `arg[-2]` is `nil`.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch: you are right, the chain stops at the interpreter. `:(`